# What is the meaning of 'de' at the end of this paragraph by Queneau?

Tags: de

From *Le Cheval Troyen* (1948):

> Le sourire du cheval devint de plus en plus paternel.
> 'Allons. Cherchez bien. Une ville fameuse. Devinez. Devinez.'
> 'Il nous les casse,' dit l'homme entre ses dents.
> Mais le cheval avait toujours un bon sourire, et les montrait
> toujours, les siennes, de dents.

I can see that it's unconventional phrasing - my question is: is there any kind of grammatical logic to that *de* before the *dents*?

Comment: Il faudrait le paragraphe dans lequel on trouve cette phrase.

Comment: Maintenant fournie

Comment: Merci, ça apporte bien quelque chose.

Comment: The joke here is that "Il nous les casse" implies an other part of the body, so "les montrait toujours" could have meant both that other part, or the "ses dents". Using the "de dents" forces the reader/listener to go back to this "Il nous les casse" in case we missed it.

Answer (score 3):

The use of « de » is described  partly by the following remark in the [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de).

> Rem. La lang. parlée et la lang. négligée (pop.) emploient le *de* disjonctif, souvent dans des phrases exclamatives.
> **a)** **Avec *en***. Eh! mais il me semble que c'en est un, de malheur, que de jeûner six semaines (Dumas père, Kean, 1836, III, p. 145).
> **b)** **Avec un *nombre***. − En voilà un de magistrat! s'écria le maître de poste (Balzac, U. Mirouët, 1841, p. 187).
> **c)** **Avec un pron. poss**. Quant au vôtre, de père... (Zola, Pot-Bouille, 1882, p. 332).
> **d)** **Devant *trop***. Garde ton argent, garde, on n'en a jamais de trop! (Dumas père, Monte-Cristo, 1848, I, 2, p. 19).

The case which applies here is the third. It can be noticed that in what precedes is found the word "dent" ("dit l'homme entre ses dents"). It will be verified through the reading of such literature as that which Queneau can provide,  that  is often found  in what precedes this linguistic context of the presence of the term introduced by "de" (either singular or plural form). In this third case, the pronoun refers to that first occurrence, and "de dents" is a confirmation of that; it should not be necessary, there is evidently some sort of redundancy, wherefrom the TLFi's terms (lang. parlée, lang négligée (pop.)).

*Other Example (case of "en")*

- — Il nous a parlé de son analyse mais brèvement, il faudrait voir.
  — J'en ai une moi d'analyse, et c'est que ça vaut rien et je veux pas en entendre parler.

Ce tour ne doit pas être utilisé dans le langage formel, et dans le langage parlé il n'est toujours pas très élégant.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the preposition *de* in that case is considered to be colloquial and usually found in oral speech rather than neat literary writing.

This is how it is defined in *Le bon usage*<sup>1</sup>:

> *De* s'emploie comme outil grammatical ou cheville syntaxique<sup>2</sup> :
> (...) dans la langue familière, devant un nom précisant l'indication donnée d'abord  par un pronom possessif ou par le pronom *en* :
> *La nôtre est faite d'opinion... un voleur*.  (A. Daudet) — *Que j'en trouve une de montre !* — *Étais-je donc le seul à avoir l'imagination de la mort dans ce régiment ? Je préférais la mienne de mort, tardive*... (L.F. Céline)<sup>3</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup> Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition, (§ 923, 12°)</sup>.
<sup><sup>2</sup> Term used by Grevisse and that is explained in those words by L. Kupferman :  « Autrement dit, *de* fait corps avec le syntagme nominal qui le suit, et c'est ensemble qu'ils fonctionnent dans le mode de constitution de l'unité sous-phrastique » (*In* Un bien grand mot : de. De la préposition au mode de quantification, « Langue française » 1996, n° 109 p. 3).</sup>
<sup><sup>3</sup> *De* is used as a grammatical tool or "syntactic peg" in colloquial speech, before a noun specifying the indication given first by a possessive pronoun or by the pronoun *en*.  (My translation)</sup>

Answer (score -2):

This "de", though beinga bit strange, is perfectly correct: it precedes the matter designed by "les siennes" (his) : When the writer supposes the reader may have a doubt about the object (his what ?), he can add a precision confirming the nature of that object: in that case, the name is given as a simple "apposition", so it must be  preceded by "*de*", like always when indicating a substance.